# i got this error when i use command ng new myprojectname to create new project in angular

Tags: angular

I got this error when i try to create new project in angular please help me to fix this
[image]

Comment: Hi, its your network connectivity problem .

Answer (score 0):

This indicates there is a network problem while installing `npm` dependencies. Please try doing it again on a stable connection.